# Having trouble with match wildcards in array

Tags: ruby

I've a master text file and exceptions file and I want to match all the words in exception file with master file and increase counter, but the trick is with wildcards.

I'm able to do without wildcards with this:

```
words = %w(aaa aab acc ccc AAA)
stop = %q(/aa./)

words.each do |x|
    if x.match(/aa./)
     puts "yes for #{x}"        
    else    
     puts "no for #{x}"
    end
end
```

=>

```
yes for aaa
yes for aab
no for acc
no for ccc
yes for AAA
```

Also which would be the best way to go about this, using arrays or some other way.

Edit: Sorry for the confusion. Yes stop has multiple wildcards and I want to match all words based on those wildcards.

```
words = %w(aaa aab acc ccc AAA)
stop = %q(aa* ac* ab*)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of your requirements is really vague.  But either the `partition` or `select` methods will work for you:

```
words = %w(aaa aab acc ccc AAA)
re = %r(aa.)i
p words.partition {|word| word.match(re)}  # => [["aaa", "aab", "AAA"], ["acc", "ccc"]]
p words.select {|word| word.match(re)}     # => ["aaa", "aab", "AAA"]
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your last comment:

```
stops= %q(aa* ac* ab*)
stops.split.collect do |wildcard| 
  re = Regexp.new(wildcard, Regexp::IGNORECASE)
  words.select {|word| word.match(re)} 
end
# => [["aaa", "aab", "acc", "AAA"], ["aaa", "aab", "acc", "AAA"], ["aaa", "aab", "acc", "AAA"]]
```

If those results surprise you, you may want to learn more about regular expressions, which are much different and more powerful than glob-style patterns. Ruby doesn't do glob matching on strings.

Comment: That works for one wildcard expression. What about multiple wildcards?

Comment: @Senthil, what do you mean? Do you mean `stop` is an array of regexps? You need to update your question and show what you mean by "multiple wildcards".

Comment: Yes. This is what I had original 'stop = %q(aa* ac* ab*)' Thanks